# Rails: Vhost config for Apache and Passenger

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, apache2, passenger

I'm trying to get a simple Rails 4 app deployed on my server which already has Apache2 and is hosting several other sites and services (ie there are several vhost configs under sites-enabled). I've had some problems doing this on my local machine as well as my test server so I'm trying first to get it working on an AWS t1.micro instance with only one vhost config. I've written a script to do most of the heavy lifting for me which is on my github at [rails-apache-passenger](https://github.com/eljaydub/rails-apache-passenger).

I have two vhost config files in the repo and have tried to get one or the other working. The script just copies over and enables one at a time.

Using the **my-ruby-app-basic** or the **my-ruby-app** vhost config I navigate to http://54.xxx.xxx.xxx/my-ruby-app/ but all I see is "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved." When I go to ttp://54.xxx.xxx.xxx/ I just get the default apache2 page ("It works!").

My /var/www/my-ruby-app/log/production.log shows

```
I, [2014-01-24T10:47:36.900542 #9612]  INFO -- : Started GET "/my-ruby-app" for 80.81.17.94 at 2014-01-24 10:47:36 +0000
F, [2014-01-24T10:47:36.902169 #9612] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/my-ruby-app"):
```

So clearly I need to modify my routes.rb file, but what am I supposed to change? As you can see from the script in the git repo, it's just the default routes.rb from `rails new`. I just want to see the default rails app landing page at this point so I'm not sure what to do to the routes.rb file.

Here are the vhost configs

**my-ruby-app-basic**

```
#This is the config suggested by the passenger module after it finishes compiling, modified for 'my-ruby-app'
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.my-ruby-app-host.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my-ruby-app/public    
  <Directory /var/www/my-ruby-app/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**my-ruby-app**

```
#Based on Apache section of Passenger documents
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.my-ruby-app-host.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  <Directory /var/www/>
     Allow from all
  </Directory>

  Alias /my-ruby-app /var/www/my-ruby-app/public
  <Location /my-ruby-app>
     PassengerBaseURI /my-ruby-app
     PassengerAppRoot /var/www/my-ruby-app
  </Location>
  <Directory /var/www/my-ruby-app/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Using Apache and Passenger is a short term solution but I want to know how to do it in any case (The long term view is that I want to maintain compatibility with Jruby and just run our app through Tomcat or Glassfish, which will no doubt be another Apache config debacle ;-) )

Comment: Do you mean you have both vhosts at the same time, or only one at the same? By the way, Passenger supports JRuby too, there's no need to use Tomcat or Glassfish if you want to use JRuby.

Comment: I mean at this point I just use one of the vhost configs - either my-ruby-app OR my-ruby-app-basic, but not both. When this goes on production there are other vhosts to worry about (all of which currently serve only static data) but this will be the only rails app.

I did not know that about Jruby and passenger, thanks for the info! I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: JRuby has been supported for more than a year now. See http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/10/30/phusion-passenger-4-0-supports-jruby-rubinius/. So both vhosts give you the same error message? Even my-ruby-app-basic doesn't work?